# I downloaded Ubuntu from the web, but it wants to install by rebooting from the CD

Tags: 13.10

I downloaded Ubuntu from the internet, but when I try to open the installation application, it wants me to reboot my computer with the CD in the tray.  You can see how this may pose a problem considering I don't have a CD since I downloaded from the website.  I tried rebooting my computer anyway, and it didn't work.  How do I fix this problem?  By the way, my current OS is Windows 8, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.10 can no longer be installed within windows. Please read : [Installation Instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

and [How to create a bootable USB 
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)